# SpecifyScriptArgs on Python debug on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to pass arguments on each python debug in VS Code?

Powershell plugin in VS code you can specify at the file `launch.json`:

`"args": [ "${command:SpecifyScriptArgs}" ]`

This opens a popup before the run so that the user can enter the args parameters for that run. I have tried this with python but it does not work. Is there some way to pass new arguments on each debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not without editing some file before each launch. If you would like such a feature then please request it at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues .